# Client-side Validation for Uploadify?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash, uploadify

I am working on a page which uses uploadify to upload several images. The requires the user to upload these files. Is there a way to validate these field(s) on the client-side, such as with jQuery or JavaScript, prior to submission? I am comfortable with doing the server-side validation, such as with PHP.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing.  You can just use the basic validate plugin but you have to manually mirror over what uploadify is bringing back.  So there are many ways to do this but here's how you'd get started.

1. When your document loads, call validate() on your form.
2. Start out with a textbox named `myFileCollection` that's blank and has `class="required"`.
3. Hook into the `OnSelect` event of Uploadify.
4. For each file selected through Uploadify, change the value in myFileCollection to the count of files.  If it's zero, blank out the text box.
5. Ignore the textbox when you submit

This way, the form would have a way to keep track of what Uploadify is up to.  Check out the event documentation of Uploadify for info on how / where to hook in:

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onselect/

Comment: Thanks, Milimetric, but I am using the Flash driven Uploadify widget `http://www.uploadify.com/`. It doesn't look like that will work for this one. :(

Comment: Oops, my bad, editing to address that.  It's possible but harder.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Milimetric. It turns out that I didn't check back quick enough, and I ended up making modifications to the uploadify jQuery plugin for this to work. Now I have native support for validation!

Comment: Oh cool, maybe share that in an answer here so others can use it.